# Celery/Django: Get result of periodic task execution

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a Django 1.7 project using Celery (latest). I have a REST API that receives some parameters, and creates, programmatically, a PeriodicTask. For testing, I'm using a period of seconds:

```
periodic_task, _= PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(name=task_label, task=task_name, interval=interval_schedule)
```

I store a reference to this tasks somewhere. I start celery beat:

```
python manage.py celery beat
```

and a worker:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

and my task runs as I can see in the worker's output.

I've set the result backend:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

and with that, I can check the task results using the **TaskMeta** model. The objects there contains the task_id (the same that I would get if I call the task with .delay() or .apply_async() ), the status, the result, everything, beautiful.

However, I can't find a connection between the **PeriodicTask** object and **TaskMeta**.

PeriodicTask has a **task** property, but its just the task name/path. The id is just a consecutive number, not the task_id from **TaskMeta**, and I really need to be able to find the task that was executed as a **PeriodicTask** with **TaskMeta** so I can offer some monitoring over the status. **TaskMeta** doesn't have any other value that allows me to identify which task ran (since I will have several ones), so at least I could give a status of the last execution.

I've checked all over Celery docs and in here, but no solution so far.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run service to monitor task have been performed by using command line

```
    python manage.py celerycam --frequency=10.0
```

More detail at:
http://www.lexev.org/en/2014/django-celery-setup/